# Using two mice on same laptop with only one USB receiver

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, mouse

I have a laptop that I use both at home and at work.

My goal is to have to carry only the laptop each time, so that I already bought a second charger.

I would like to have two wireless mice (one at home and another at work) but using the same USB receiver, because I have few usb ports...

So I thought of buying two identical wirelss mice, call them A and B, plug in the receiver of A into my laptop and leave it always there. USB receiver of mouse B would be left fully unused (potentially thrown away).

For sure mouse A will work, but will mouse B work?

Just to confirm: the two mice will never get close one to the other, since one is at work and the other at home...

I m thinking of (two) basic Logitech mice and I am using Win7.

Comment: 2 Bluetooth mice might be the better way to go

Comment: @Blaine thx - if possible i d like to avoid since I have already one (non-bluetooth) mouse. With your solution I d need to buy two bluetooth mice compared to only one non-bluetooth.

Comment: Would advise you to go with the bluetooth mice, as RF Wireless mice are *sometimes* paired with the receiver and If it gets somehow lost or damaged, then you would have to get a new mouse. BE careful with that !

Comment: @C0deDaedalus I see you agreeing with Blaine.. My hope is to avoid this b/c, since I have already one wireless mouse I m comparing: a) spending 20 EUR and get only one other wireless mouse b) speding 100 EUR to get two bluetooth mice.

Comment: @Giulio why would you need to buy 2 bluetooth mice? You should be fine continuing to use your RF mouse in one location and buy a new bluetooth mouse for the other

Comment: @Blaine sure, it was just to be consistent :)

Comment: @Blaine also another reason to do so is to have exactly the same mouse at work and at home.. If it s different, it happens to me that if i set the "right speed" from control panel for one mouse, then the other will be too slow or too quick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have purchased two Logitech M235 mice with Unifying receiver and they are paired to the same receiver and I can use the two mice simultaneously.

I have also purchased a non-Unifying Logitech M185 mouse that is paired with two Logitech Nano receivers and I can use the same mouse on two PCs simultaneously.

With non-Unifying Logitech peripherals, only the receiver store the pairing information so you can have the same non-Unifying mouse paired with two Logitech Nano receivers simultaneously (but you can't have two non-Unifying mice paired with one Logitech Nano receiver)

Logitech Unifying peripherals such as the M235 do store the pairing information, so when you pair to a new Logitech Unifying receiver, the peripheral device will no longer communicate with the old Unifying receiver. (so you can pair two Unifying mice with one Unifying receiver, but you can't have a Unifying mouse paired with two Unifying receivers)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using Logitech mice in order to have it unified under one bluetooth connection on the same [USB Logitech Unifying Receiver](https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/unifying-receiver-usb) with other Logitech devices.

Actually you can connect up to 6 Logitech wireless devices (mice, keyboards, etc) on the same receiver.

> ONE RECEIVER – 6 DEVICES
>
> Connect up to 6 compatible keyboards and mice to one computer with a single Unifying receiver and forget the hassle of multiple USB receivers.
>
> https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/unifying-receiver-usb

Modern Logitech mice and keyboards all come with a Unifying Receiver.

This little dongle plugs into a USB port and can connect up to six Logitech devices to your system. Thus, if you want to use multiple keyboards or mice and they’re all Logitech, you can save a few USB ports [[source](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/teamplayer-use-multiple-keyboard-and-mice-on-one-system/)]

Comment: thx this looks interesting - not all Logitech mice are supported by Unifying Receiver, right? I have a cheap wireless Logitech mouse. I does not have this "little orange sun" anywhere (not on receiver nor on mouse). Will that work if i buy another mouse with a UR? I.e. where is the technology, in the mouse, in the reciever on must be in both?

Comment: @Giulio Yes you have at first to have a receiver with the the Unifying logo. For supported devices, click **Works with these products** on this [link](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/unifying). If you liked my answer vote it up or/and check it as accepted.